# django for-loop to calculate loan repyament and interest for a period only displaying the last iteration

Tags: django, django-views

I am building a loan system to calculate the repayment period. am having this issue when i run the code it only display the last row.   below is my view.py
please i need it to display all the rows not only the last row

```
def sveloan(request):
    if 'userid' in request.session:
        if request.method == 'POST':
                            
              balance = 120000

              annual_interest_rate = 42

              monthly_payment_rate =0.3

              monthly_interest_rate = annual_interest_rate / 12

              monthly_payment = monthly_payment_rate * balance

              new_balance= (balance - monthly_payment) * (1 + monthly_interest_rate)

              for month in range(1, 6):

                  monthly_payment = 20000

                  balance = (balance - monthly_payment)

                  rateint = (balance / 100 * monthly_interest_rate)

                  mydist = ('Month: %d \n Minimum monthly payment: %g \n Remaining balance: %g \n Minimum Interest payment: %g'\
                      % (month, round(monthly_payment, 2), round(balance,2), round(rateint, 2)))


                  context={
                      'mylist': mydist
                  }
                      
              
              return render(request,'loantest.html',context)

              
        else:
            return render(request,'index.html')
           
    else:
        return render(request,'index.html')
```

In my template:

```
{% for p in mylist %}

{{p}}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've just got a couple small things that need to be adjusted. Here's my quick attempt at repairing that code. I've added explanation comments inline:

```
def sveloan(request):
    if 'userid' in request.session:
        if request.method == 'POST':

            balance = 120000

            annual_interest_rate = 42

            monthly_payment_rate = 0.3

            monthly_interest_rate = annual_interest_rate / 12

            monthly_payment = monthly_payment_rate * balance

            new_balance = (balance - monthly_payment) * (1 + monthly_interest_rate)

            # setting up a collector here for the individual mydist tuples/rows
            mylist = []

            for month in range(1, 6):
                monthly_payment = 20000

                balance = (balance - monthly_payment)

                rateint = (balance / 100 * monthly_interest_rate)

                mydist = (
                        'Month: %d \n Minimum monthly payment: %g \n Remaining balance: %g \n Minimum Interest payment: %g' \
                        % (month, round(monthly_payment, 2), round(balance, 2), round(rateint, 2)))

                # add each mydist tuple to the mylist collector
                mylist.append(mydist)

            # de-indenting this, it should not be within your for loop
            context = {
                # use the mylist value, which now has all of the rows
                'mylist': mylist
            }

            return render(request, 'loantest.html', context)


        else:
            return render(request, 'index.html')

    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is overwriting `mylist` every iteration of the for loop and therefore only capturing the last iteration.

To solve this you could append the `mydist` variable to python list declared outside the loop and append to it every iteration. Then, pass that list to the context after the loop is finished. For example:

```
mylist = []

for month in range(1, 6):
    # whatever code
    mydist = 'whatever value'
    mylist.append(mydist)

context = {
    'mylist': mydist
}
```